# How to transform a collection of loans into a collection of net lenders using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, group-by

Imagine the following pairs:

```
T1, T2 -> 100
T1, T2 -> 30
T2, T1 -> 50
T3, T1 -> 400
```

First position means lender and second position means borrower, number after arrow is the amount.

The final output that I need is something like that:

```
T1, T2 -> 80
T3, T1 -> 400
```

which tells me what are the net lenders (first position). How can I achieve it in Kotlin?

I know how to get something intermediate:

```
T1, T2 -> 130
T2, T1 -> 50
T3, T1 -> 400
```

Which is fairly easy using groupBy, but I don't know how to transform it into the output that I need in an elegant way.

Comment: To clarify, what do the items in the second position of the output mean?

Comment: First position before the arrow is the lender, second position is the borrower. Number after the arrow is the amount lent.

Comment: One idea that I just had is to always have T1, T2 in the output. If T1 is the net lender final amount will be positive, otherwise it will be negative.

Comment: Right, but in your example final output T2 is missing, so is it a final collection of all the money a particular lender owes a particular borrower?

Comment: If you have already done something intermediate, it would be nice to post it

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code which seems to implement it

```
fun main() {

    val loans = listOf(
        (("T1" to "T2") to 100),
        (("T1" to "T2") to 30),
        (("T2" to "T1") to 50),
        (("T3" to "T1") to 400),
        (("T1" to "T3") to 400)
    )

    val result = loans
        .groupBy { (pair, amount) ->
            linkedSetOf(pair.component1(), pair.component2())
        }
        .map { (k, v) ->
            k to v.map { (k2, v2) -> if (k.elementAt(0) == k2.component1()) k2 to v2 else k2 to -v2 }
        }
        .map { (k, v) ->
            k to v.map { (_, amount)  -> amount }.sum()
        }.map { (k , v) ->
            if (v >= 0) k.elementAt(0) to k.elementAt(1) to v
            else k.elementAt(1) to k.elementAt(0) to -v
        }

    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Yes your code works and it matches with the expected fonctionality. So what do you want more ?